# Asset volumes with dynamic subfolder

Tags: assets, matrix, user-profile, assets-field, volumes

I have an asset volume which uses dynamic subfolders on the field level.

I have an assets volume called 'members'.
In a matrix field on the user profile tab there is an image field that sets its upload directory to be `{owner.author.username}` within the members volume.
In my filesystem there is a folder called `web/images/members/username` (where username is the actual username). This folder contains images.

FYI this Craft site is 5 years old and has recently gone through a major upgrade to Craft v3.

I cannot get the assets field to show existing images when trying to edit it in the admin panel.

I have tried various permutations in the dynamic subfolder path, for example:

- `{owner.username}`
- `{currentUser.username}`
- `{{currentUser.username}}`

But in no situation can I get the field to see the images in the subfolder.

There are fields in matrixes and also basic asset fields not in matrixes that have this issue, so I need assistance in how to set up the matrix asset fields and non-matrix asset fields to be able to see the same folder.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a field outside the Matrix, you can use `{username}` and for the one in the Matrix, use `{owner.username}` - [see docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/assets-fields.html#dynamic-subfolder-paths)

You might need to run Utilities → Asset Indexes.